# svg favicon appearing really small in Vite React App

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am currently building my personal portfolio and I have tried to upload a svg favicon logo and its for some reason appearing really small.
This is what my svg is appearing as after converting the PNG to SVG format - any help on how to fix this?
[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy616.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="600.000000pt" height="600.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 500.000000 500.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.16, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2019
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,500.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M2285 3483 c-345 -73 -626 -289 -779 -600 -40 -81 -80 -202 -95 -287
-16 -88 -13 -311 4 -403 79 -415 386 -745 800 -860 93 -26 112 -28 285 -27
168 0 194 3 280 26 197 55 360 150 503 294 215 219 316 464 317 770 0 307
-103 564 -310 773 -167 169 -369 277 -590 317 -100 18 -326 16 -415 -3z m399
-77 c349 -67 635 -302 767 -631 95 -238 92 -530 -7 -762 -52 -120 -94 -188
-174 -281 -141 -163 -313 -269 -535 -328 -56 -15 -104 -19 -245 -18 -162 0
-182 2 -265 28 -361 111 -617 372 -717 733 -19 67 -22 105 -22 258 0 168 2
186 27 270 50 162 124 296 230 412 145 158 360 278 572 318 95 18 277 18 369
1z"/>
<path d="M2360 3096 c-264 -77 -335 -336 -155 -571 21 -27 154 -187 294 -355
141 -168 262 -313 269 -322 12 -15 9 -21 -34 -47 -69 -45 -133 -63 -222 -63
-125 0 -241 47 -311 127 -40 46 -51 73 -59 150 -6 48 -11 60 -26 63 -39 8 -46
-22 -46 -203 0 -181 7 -211 46 -203 16 3 19 13 22 75 l3 71 32 -30 c41 -37
126 -81 202 -103 44 -13 84 -16 165 -13 93 4 115 8 173 36 207 97 289 313 192
507 -14 28 -160 209 -325 404 -165 195 -300 358 -300 362 0 3 24 17 53 29 77
34 203 39 278 11 103 -39 188 -137 189 -216 0 -29 15 -55 31 -55 4 0 15 7 23
16 13 13 16 43 16 168 0 162 -6 182 -47 174 -14 -3 -19 -15 -21 -61 l-3 -58
-39 31 c-76 60 -144 83 -255 86 -62 2 -117 -2 -145 -10z m155 -511 c158 -187
300 -359 315 -383 38 -58 56 -154 40 -213 -7 -24 -19 -56 -26 -72 l-15 -27
-271 322 c-149 178 -285 341 -301 363 -73 99 -100 215 -68 295 14 35 32 63 36
58 2 -2 132 -156 290 -343z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I have tried manually changing the height and widths which didn't seem to do much

Comment: Your viewBox is to large and doesn't match your graphic. Try `viewBox="140 150 220 220"`` . You can calculate a tight viewBox in JS via `svg.getBBox();` method

Comment: Hi that worked! thank you! did you use that method to figure out those precise numbers?

Comment: Yes, `getBBox()` is natively supported in all modern browsers. Your svg need to be appended to the DOM otherwise it return 0;

Comment: awesome!! thats really cool and useful to know thanks for sharing and helping me :D

Answer (score 0):

your SVG favicon has the viewBox set to `0 0 500.000000 500.000000` which means the SVg has a default of 500x500 units, However, the w and h attributes are set to `600.000000pt`, which might cause the SVG to appear smaller than expected.

to try to fix this issue you should make sure that the viewBox and width/height attributes are consistent.

so you might want to do something like this:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <!-- rest of svg path -->
</svg>
```

this code has the viewBox set to `0 0 100 100` and w / h attributes also to `100`

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question!!! :) 
i tired what you suggested but the favicon has now disappeared with those viewbox and w / h attributes